# split string using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, split

I'm trying to split a string pulled from a JSON array in angular. I've tried using the angular [{{filter}}](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) but not sure I'm on the right track. I want each tag in it's own link. ie `<a ng-href="">tall</a> | <a ng-href="">large</a> etc...`

```
<body ng-app="feedApp">
   <div ng-controller="FeedController as feedCtrl">
       <ul class="tags">
         <li>Tags: </li>
         <li>
            <a ng-href="http://www.example.com/{{feed.tags|filter:' '}}" ng-repeat="feed in feedCtrl.feeds">{{feed.tags|filter:' '}} &nbsp;|&nbsp; </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('feedApp', [ ]);

app.controller('FeedController', ['$http', '$scope',function($http, $scope){
    var array = this;
    array.feeds = [ ];
    $http.get('tags.json').success(function(data){
    array.feeds = data;
});
```

JSON

```
[
    {
       "tags": "tall large winner skill"
    },

    {
       "tags": "short knowledge"
    },
]
```

I have a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/vvJ6DsMUZQx3IK3DhP9r?p=preview) that shows the code above - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to manipulate the `data` read from `tags.json` producing a simple array with a tag for each element. To do so, you can use simple JavaScript code:

```
  $http.get('tags.json').success(function(data) {
    var splittedTags = data.map(function(e) {
      return e.tags.split(' ');
    });
    array.feeds = splittedTags.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.concat(b);
    });
  });
```

First I use `Array.prototype.map()` to extract from every object inside `data` the value of `tags` attribute and split it. This produce an array of array. I use the `Array.prototype.reduce()` to flatten the array and produce and array with the single tags.

Then, in the HTML page I remove the Angular.js `filter` and use directly the `feed` value:

```
  <li>
    <a ng-href="http://www.example.com/{{feed}}" ng-repeat="feed in feedCtrl.feeds">{{feed}} &nbsp;|&nbsp; </a>
  </li>
```

[Here you can find the PLUNKER with the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/l2umjxL5n5nzs0vkoRRr?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it.

First you need to split the string by defining the delimiter (in your case is space). You then assign it to your scope:

```
var app = angular.module('feedApp', []);

app.controller('FeedController', ['$http', '$scope',function($http, $scope){
    var array = this;
    array.feeds = [ ];
    var strings = [];

    $http.get('tags.json').success(function(data){
      data.map(function(elem) {
        strings.push(elem.tags.split(' '));
      });

      array.feeds = strings;
    });
}]);
```

If you are done with this in your template you can iterate over your array with `ng-repeat` recursively:

```
<body ng-controller="FeedController as feedCtrl">
    <ul class="tags">
      <li>Tags: </li>
      <li>
        <div ng-repeat="feeds in feedCtrl.feeds">
          <div class="link" ng-repeat="(key, value) in feeds">
            <a ng-href="http://www.example.com/{{value}}" >{{value}} &nbsp;|&nbsp; </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Here is the working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ctAopvSQrnl3DdECFFhy?p=preview).